# Swift how to display textStorage on watch

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a textView with images, different text styles etc. I wanna display it on watch. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is that a UITextView that you currently have on iOS?

Comment: Yes. I have UITextView with images and different styles of font in iOS app. And I'd like to display this text and images on watch.

Comment: So you'll need to use a WKInterfaceLabel and call setAttributedText on it. Check out this as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28748030/370965

Comment: Thanks:) I'll check it at the moment because now I'm fighting with sending this text to Watch(I thought it's easier).

Comment: Check out MMWormhole for a simple message sending implementation: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole

Comment: It didn't work:( But I've just done it with WCSession

Comment: I have a problem with images - I append this attributed string to label and I receive: "Attributed string '￼' contains NSAttachmentAttributeName. Removed".

Answer (score 0):

It is not a code for displaying NSAttributedString on apple watch, but I use it for sending NSAttributedString with images in the form which will be easier to display.
Code may not be a high-quality(I am almost sure it isn't, especially scaling images).

```
    func sendText(stext: NSMutableAttributedString) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    let range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, stext.length)
    stext.enumerateAttributesInRange(range, options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions.init(rawValue: 0), usingBlock: { (dic: [String:AnyObject]?, rang:NSRange!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in


        self.attachement = dic as NSDictionary!
        self.attachement.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock({ (key:AnyObject?, obj:AnyObject?, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in


            let stri = key as! NSString!
            if stri == "NSAttachment"{
                let att:NSTextAttachment = obj as! NSTextAttachment
                if att.image == nil{
                    print("no image")
                }else{
                    var im:UIImage = att.image!

                    print("image exists")

                    if im.size.height > 340 && im.size.width > 272 {
                        let heightScale: CGFloat = self.textView.frame.size.height / im.size.height
                        let widthScale: CGFloat = self.textView.frame.size.width / im.size.width

                        if heightScale < widthScale {
                            let height = im.size.height * heightScale * 0.7
                            let width = im.size.width * heightScale * 0.7
                            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height))
                            im.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
                            im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                        } else {
                            let height = im.size.height * widthScale * 0.7
                            let width = im.size.width * widthScale * 0.7
                            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height))
                            im.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
                            im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                        }

                    }
                    self.lastRange = rang.location
                    self.finalForWatch.append(NSAttributedString(attributedString: stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, rang.location))))
                    self.finalForWatch.append(im)

                }
            }
            if self.lastRange == 0 {
                self.finalForWatch.append(stext)
            } else {
                self.finalForWatch.append(NSAttributedString(attributedString: stext.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(1, stext.length-1))))
            }
        })

    })
        let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.finalForWatch)
        let applicationDict = ["done" : data]

        let documentDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)

        let fileDestinationUrl = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.txt")

        do{
            try data.writeToURL(fileDestinationUrl, atomically: true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error writing to url \(fileDestinationUrl)")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

          self.session?.transferFile(fileDestinationUrl, metadata: nil)

    }
}
```

I save everything into a file and use a sendFile method because appllicationContext, userInfo and messages always return "too big payloads".